# Generate similar methods programmatically

Tags: python, comparative-review

I'm repeatedly faced with writing proxy classes for various purposes, recently lazy evaluation and IPC. This usually means having a single method pattern, which just forwards the call. I'm having a hard time to do this efficiently and readable.

---

Let's consider an example of a (trimmed down) lazy evaluation proxy:

```
class Lazy(object):
    """Mockup of a Lazy-Evaluation proxy"""
    def __init__(self, call, *args, **kwargs):
        self._resolve=lambda: call(*args, **kwargs)

    def __getattr__(self, name):
        # forward getattr
        return getattr(self._resolve(), name)

    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # forward call
        return self._resolve()(*args, **kwargs)
```

Basically, *every* method could be logically defined by a factory:

```
def make_lazy_method(name):
    def method(self, *args, **kwargs):
        target = self._resolve()
        return getattr(target, name)(*args, **kwargs)
    return method
```

Usually, I cannot rely on `__getattr__`, `__setattr__` fetching methods for me, since there may be scoping involved (e.g. holding a lock *during* a method call) or I need special methods (e.g. `__add__`, `__call__`, ...).

So far, I have some approaches, which all have quite some downsides. Since they all seem convoluted somehow, my question is which one(s) are not just hacks but follow best practice.

Note that the code in question is not the resulting class, but the way of generating said class.

- The obvious one is to do everything by hand.

  ```
  class LazyVerbose(Lazy):
      def __add__(self, other):
          return self._resolve() + other

      def __radd__(self, other):
          return other + self._resolve()
      # roughly 280 more lines of code for other operators
  ```

  This works reliably, but creates tons of duplicate code. It is difficult to write, read and maintain.
- In older projects, I've modified the class' locals during creation.

  ```
  import operator
  class LazyLocals(Lazy):
      cls_locals = locals()
      cls_locals.update({'__%s__' % name: make_lazy_method('__%s__' % name) for name in dir(operator) if '__%s__' % name in dir(operator)})
  ```

  While this worked so far, the [docs explicitly advice against it](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html#locals) and it seems to be [differently defined across implementations](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8028772/5349916).
- Using `exec` to [run method code created programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36057436/5349916).

  Portable, but kills any chance at introspection, tracebacks, maintainability or readability. Also, `exec`.
- Using a custom metaclass.

  ```
  import operator
  class WrappedType(type):
      def __new__(mcs, name, bases, class_dict):
          assert 'proxy_factory' in class_dict and 'proxy_methods' in class_dict, 'class def must provide proxy_methods/_factory'
          proxy_factory = class_dict.pop('proxy_factory')
          for meth_name in class_dict.pop('proxy_methods'):
              class_dict[meth_name] = proxy_factory(meth_name)
          return type.__new__(mcs, name, bases, class_dict)

  class LazyMeta(Lazy, metaclass=WrappedType):
      proxy_factory = make_lazy_method
      proxy_methods = ['__%s__' % name for name in dir(operator) if '__%s__' % name in dir(operator)]
  ```

  Somewhat difficult to understand (i.e. maintain) for many people: separates definition and implementation. Setting a metaclass for py2 *and* py3 is also not easily portable without third party packages.

  ```
  LazyMetaSix = WrappedType.__new__(
      WrappedType,
      'LazyMetaSix',
      (Lazy,),
      dict(
          proxy_factory = make_lazy_method,
          proxy_methods = ['__%s__' % name for name in dir(operator) if '__%s__' % name in dir(operator)])
      )
  ```

---

The above code can be tested with:

```
for cls in (LazyVerbose, LazyLocals, LazyMetaSix):
    lazy_obj = cls(lambda a: a*a, 4)
    print(cls.__name__, '__add__', lazy_obj + 10, lazy_obj + 12)
```

Python version 2.6+ and 3.3+ need to be supported.

Comment: You appear to be asking what the best approach is. The best approach will depend on the rest of the application. Please take a look at the [help/on-topic] and note Code Review does not deal in hypothetical examples. What is your specific question?

Comment: @Mast the point is that I non-hypothetically use all four variants, but stating each specific class/use case would be unreadable. The code in question is the code *generating* the classes, not the classes created by it. The question is whether my ways of creating classes follow best practice - and since there are four, which one is the closest.

Comment: And it has to work on all mentioned Python versions?

Comment: @MisterMiyagi This code looks like it's [not real code](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/3652/42401). To improve the question you should remove explicit example code flags like `# roughly 50 more operators`, `# init`. And you should add the code that you're using, what is `self._resolve()`, `operator` and how is `self` defined in `make_lazy_method`. All this makes it seem like example code, hypothetical code or pseudocode. All of these combined make it _very_ hard to understand what your code even does.

Comment: @JoeWallis Sorry for any inconvenience and thanks for the feedback. I've added all missing code now and cleaned up. `self._resolve()` is inherited from `Lazy`, `operator` is the default `operator` package. I've left in the `# ... operators` comment since it translates to 281 LOC which don't add anything to the code here, but are the major problem of the approach.

Comment: @Mast Yes, 2.6+ and 3.3+ are required.